# Infinite connected $k$-regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Is it true that for any integer $k\geq 3$ there are $\aleph_0$ many connected countably infinite, pairwise non-isomorphic $k$-regular graphs?

Comment: For each $k\ge 3$ there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ non-isomorphic graphs of valency $k$ (necessarily countable), obtained as Cayley graphs of the same number of pairwise non-quasi-isometric finitely generated groups. But of course without transitivity assumption it's much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take an $n$-cycle, add an infinite tree of the right degree at each vertex of the cycle (the vertex on the cycle having degree 2 less in the tree than the other vertices of the tree). This has only one cycle and it is of length $n$. So the graphs you get for two different values of $n$ are non-isomorphic.

Comment: Start with a "chain of cycles", i.e. cycles $(C_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$, with an edge from $C_n$ to $C_{n+1}$, and adapt the attached trees accordingly. Then altering the cycle lengths even gives you $2^{\aleph_0}$ many non-isomorphic such graphs.

Comment: Nice! @FlorianLehner